# java call oracle procedure with %rowtype parameter

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, rowtype

I have been given an oracle procedure with the in out parameter %rowtype,like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cleansing(
       io_user IN OUT USER%rowtype
)
IS
BEGIN
  --some pl/sql code

END cleansing;
```

USER is a table with more than **100 columns**, I want to call the procedure by Java.
I can't change the procedure, because they are already used by other project.
I can't add procedure to database, because I don't have the permission to do it.
I google it, but can't find a good way to handle this.
what I want to do is:
1. pass the parameter.
2. get the parameter. some java demo code:

```
String sql = "{call cleansing(?)}";
try {
    dbConnection = getDBConnection();
    callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(sql);
    callableStatement.setXXX()//I don't know
    callableStatement.registerOUTParameter(1, //I don't know the type.);
```

can anyone help me and give some demo code? no change to database and in out parameter mapping with java

Comment: no, I have some constraint condition. And the link you provide doesn't give the answer. I don't think that oracle can't support it, I think it's verty basic feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible but it's not really straightforward. You have to create something of type USER%ROWTYPE at runtime and use that to call your stored procedure. Take a look [here](http://blog.orindasoft.com/2010/03/trying-to-use-object-types-record-types.html) for details.

To get output values as well, you have to do something extra, along the line of Sumit's comment. Basically, after your procedure call, you open a cursor that selects the relevant data from the `USER` parameter.

So you get a database statement as follows (pseudocode):

```
string sql =
   "declare
        user_param user%rowtype;
    begin
        -- Set necessary parameters 
        user_param.col0 := :p0In;
        user_param.col1 := :p1In;
        ...

        -- Call procedure.
        cleansing(io_user => user_param);

        -- Read necessary output values into cursor.
        open :pOut for select user_param.col99 as col99
                              user_param.col98 as col98
                              ...
                       from dual;
    end;"
```

You call this entire statement the usual way, but you register a cursor out parameter (unfortunately, Java is a very long time ago for me so I'm not sure on the exact syntax).

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter("pOut", OracleTypes.CURSOR);
...
callableStatement.execute();
...
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject("pOut");
// Read from result set.
```

**EDIT**: I turned this into a [blogpost](http://itq.nl/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-with-rowtype-inout-parameter-directly-from-code/). Code examples are in C# but the idea is the same.

Comment: thanks for your link, but how to get the out or in out parameter ?is ? := p_row.text_col ;? := p_row.date_col ;? := p_row.num_col ; work?

Comment: Good question... :) Have to think about it.

Comment: What I would do is try to select the output from the proc into a sys_refcursor. Basically change your sql to be a plsql begin end block, and then call your proc in that block outputing to a local variable in that block and then output a cursor that is bound to your out parameter in java. You would just use ? := yourcursor. If you wanted to return the scalars, you would just do ?:=p_row.text_col; ?:=p_row.date_col;... in succession after you call your proc and then register them as outputs in the same order. does that make sense? I dont think you need to do a set on the java out parameter.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, although it took some time to figure out the details...